# MFC multiple radio buttons groups on dialog

Tags: mfc, radio-button

I have 2 groups of radio boxes on a dialog. How can I specify which button is in which group? Because right now when I select one, all the others get unselected, even the ones from the other group.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The tab order of the dialog, and the `Group` property completely dictates which radio buttons belong to which groups.

Each radio button belongs to the group of the previous main radio button in the tab order.  The main radio button has the Group property set to `True`.

You can set the tab order by going to the dialog editor and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  You then click on each control from 1 to N in the order you want the tabbing to go.